# TabBar not showing when moving from viewController to tabBarViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

When a go from a viewController to a tabBarViewController (meaning one of the two view controllers that is one of the tabs), the tab bar does not appear. When I move between either of the view controllers that are in the tab Bar controller instead, the tab bar works properly and it appears. Why does the tab bar seem to break when moving between a tab bar view controller and a regular view controller? 
Thanks.

Comment: Sound like you have ViewController1 and ViewController2 on as tabs on the tabBar.  But it sounds like you are trying to to navigate from ViewController1 to ViewController2 by pressing a button on ViewController1?  If so why?

Comment: ViewController1 and ViewController2 are tabs on the tabBar. I am trying to go from ViewController1 to ViewController3, which is not a tab on the tab bar, using a Push Segue. When I return from ViewController3 to Viewcontroller1, the tabBar for viewController1 is no longer showing.

Comment: You need to look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)